# mocking - request and the response inside django rest fbv

Tags: python, django, rest, unit-testing

I have 3 players.
1. client : Any mobile devices
2. `poink`: Django server
3. `platform`: Another server

The mechanic is 
1. `client` POST to `poink`
2. `poink` `GET` to `platform`
3. `platform` response back to `poink`
4. `poink` responses back to `client`

`views.py`
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/111fde80317e96523a34bb297e5ccf25
`tests.py`
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/565b458716dbf5358d2ad7ba1ff2ee6b
`output.txt`
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/9a93d5fc5237b403b4d1d2c8ee3c352e

**Goal:**
I want to run integration test on this endpoint, but I do not want to shoot the real endpoint

**Reads:**
[python mock Requests and the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753390/python-mock-requests-and-the-response)
[Python mock, django and requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069541/python-mock-django-and-requests)
[mocking functions using python mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286390/mocking-functions-using-python-mock)
http://engineroom.trackmaven.com/blog/real-life-mocking/

**Problem:**
It is not `mock` my object. It raises the error you can see from `output.txt`

**Workaround:**
I do not know what is the best practice on this integration test. But I do more simplification on it.

1. Let the login function be a plain function
2. `request` is created in the test environment
3. `patch` the function `requests.get`

Here is the confirmed code. Thanks to Andrew Backer

```
def test_mobile_send_wrong_session_key(db):
    from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    url = reverse('auth:login')
    data = {'session_key': 'Wrong value'}
    request = factory.post(url, data)
    from poinkbackend.apps.authentications.views import login
    with patch('requests.get') as mock_get:
        # `Platform` response with 400 to `Poink`
        mock_get.return_value.ok = False
        mock_get.return_value.status_code = 400
        mock_get.return_value.text = 'Bad Request El'
        res = login(request)
    assert 406 == res.status_code
```

**Reference:**
https://realpython.com/blog/python/testing-third-party-apis-with-mocks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what is the best practice on this integration test. But I do more simplification on it.

1. Let the login function be a plain function
2. `request` is created in the test environment
3. `patch` the function `requests.get`

**Reference:**
https://realpython.com/blog/python/testing-third-party-apis-with-mocks/

```
def test_mobile_send_wrong_session_key(db):
    from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    url = reverse('auth:login')
    data = {'session_key': 'Wrong value'}
    request = factory.post(url, data)
    from poinkbackend.apps.authentications.views import login
    with patch('requests.get') as mock_get:
        # `Platform` response with 400 to `Poink`
        mock_get.return_value.ok = False
        mock_get.return_value.status_code = 400
        mock_get.return_value.text = 'Bad Request El'
        res = login(request)
    assert 406 == res.status_code
```

Answer (score 1):

Your endpoint mock is ok, but the test you are running is trying to set something in the database. That gives two choices:

- either you mock the database too
- or you can use a [django TestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase) that will spawn a test database, and delete it at the end of the test

Comment: Thanks for mentioning about database. I use `pytest`. Then the actual database is untouched.